# What are the negative test scenarios you would run for the below cases

Tags: test-design, test-planning

What are the negative test scenarios you would run for the below cases:

[image]

Comment: You mean test scenarios? The most obvious one would be checking what happens when connection between two parts of the system is not possible, e.g: Game Server cannot pass reward purchase request to the database.

Comment: yes, exactly . thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you say negative tests, I think things outside the intended use / happy path of the system.
Skimming over the above details, my first thoughts for negative tests would be to submit dates outside the valid range, invalid dates (Nov. 31), and depending on the system with the start & end date the same.  Reward purchase request submit a negative value, value of zero, that requires 1 or more points than available, and depending on the title field try sending 31+ characters, or if it really is a text field send numbers.

I'm sure there are others but this is just a quick skim, before I've finished my first cup of coffee this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking at this from a number of angles. A non-exhaustive list might contain:

**Boundary analysis**

-1, 0, 1 `Point Cost`

**Validation**

1. End date before start date
2. Alphanumeric `Point Cost`
3. Title prevents > 30 characters
4. Entering different date formats (mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, yyyy,mm,dd)

**Connectivity**

Observing system behaviour when one of more connections is broken/offline